# Ayuda con la validacion de un login con privilegios de usuario

Tags: php, html, mysql

Quiero hacer un login con privilegios de usuarios, tengo una base de datos llamada **login**, con una tabla **cuentas** con los campos **usuario**, **contrasena** y **tipo_cuenta**. En los formularios para iniciar sesión solo tengo 2 inputs:  *usuario* y *contraseña*. Al crear las cuentas utilicé la función password_hash() para encriptar la contraseña y el tipo de usuario los ingresé con un input de tipo select con las opciones Usuario y administrador.

Este es el archivo que procesa los datos enviados por el formulario:
[image: Imagen del codigo que procesa el login]

El inicio de sesión es ejecutado correctamente y se procesa la contraseña encriptada pero me gustaría encontrar la forma de redireccionar a una página u otra según el tipo de usuario que ingrese (administrador una vista, usuario otra vista). He probado diferentes `if else` dentro del `if(contador>0)` de la línea 23 pero nada me resulta.

Espero haberme explicado bien, sería de mucha ayuda sus sugerencias. Gracias

---

**Gracias a todos** por sus sugerencias, adapté el código de @A.Palacio y me funcionó. El código quedó así:

```
setAttribute (PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $sql= "SELECT * FROM cuentas where usuario= :user";
  $resultado=$conexion->prepare($sql);
  $resultado->execute(array(":user"=>$usuario));
$registro=$resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($registro) {
         if (password_verify($password,$registro['contrasena'])) {

            if ($registro['tipo_cuenta'] == 'Administrador') {
                $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;

                header("Location:administrador.php");

            } else if($registro['tipo_cuenta'] == 'Usuario'){

                $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
                header("Location:usuario.php");
            }

         } else {
            echo "Contraseña incorrecta";
         }
} else {
    echo "Usuario no existe";
}

  } catch (Exception $e) {
    die(" Error: " . $e->getMessage());
  }
```

Comment: Bienvenido de preferencia cuando pongas codigo sea texto para poder replicar errores o entender mejor la pregunta

Comment: Probaste poner luego del session_start un **IF**  q pregunte si es admin o no. Algo como IF($_SESSION["tipo_usuario"]) == 1; o como sea q indiques si es admin o no

Comment: Por favor coloca tu código con las herramientas de SOes para que sea editable y te podamos ayudar mejor. No veo en tu imagen el select que comentas en la descripción con el tipo de usuario. Tampoco veo que lo captures en el back.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [Te he votado negativamente porque una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/)

Comment: Lo se, solo estoy un poco confundido con la organizacion de los comentarios y la edición de las preguntas.

Comment: Las soluciones deben publicarse como respuesta no como una edición de la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo este codigo a modo de ejemplo, lo puedes adaptar a tu manera:

```
<?php 
session_start();
try{
    $usuario = 'root';
    $password='';

    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pruebas', $usuario, $password);

    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

}catch(PDOException $e){

    echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();

}

$usuario = 'Antonio';
$password = '123';

$sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nombre = :usuario'); 
$sql->execute(array(':usuario' => $usuario));
$resultado = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($resultado) { //Retorna TRUE en caso de encontrar datos referentes al USUARIO
         if (password_verify($password,$resultado['password'])) {//Validamos que coincidan las Contraseñas

            if ($resultado['tipo_cuenta'] == 'Administrador') {//Validamos los Tipos de Cuenta del Usuario

                $_SESSION['nombre'] = $usuario;
                echo "Eres Administrador";
                //header("Location: administrador.php");

            } else if($resultado['tipo_cuenta'] == 'Normal'){

                $_SESSION['nombre'] = $usuario;
                echo "Eres Normal";
                //header("Location: normal.php"); 
            }

         } else {
            echo "Contraseña incorrecta";
         }

} else {
    echo "Usuario no existe";
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: Oye @A.Palacio  muchas gracias, lo adapté y me funcionó. Crei que era necesario hacer un while para  la variable **$registro** pero bastó con el **if** Me has salvado!

Answer (score 1):

tu código no dice ¿Qué tiene la tabla `users`?, ¿Cómo manejas los distintos tipos?.

En general se guarda el tipo de usuario en algún lado, supongamos que lo tienes en la tabla `users`, entonces cuando accedes al `$registro` y luego de verificar la contraseña, debes tener un `if` que pregunte por el tipo, algo así como:

```
if ($registro['tipo_de_usuario'] == "Admin"){
   header("..."); // pagina de admin
}
else ($registro['tipo_de_usuario'] == "Normal"){
   header("..."); // pagina de usuario normal
}
```

Espero que te sirva esta explicación.

Comment: Mi tabla se llama **cuenta** y tiene los campos usuario, contrasena y tipo_cuenta.  Justo ese if que me propones lo utilicé dentro del if de la linea 23, pero no me funcionó.

Answer (score 1):

yo pondria luego del **session_start**

```
switch ($_SESSION['tipo_usuario']) {
  case 'Admin':
    header("location:administrador.php");
  break;
  case 'RegularUser':
    header("location:index.php");
  break;
}
```

No se como cargas el valor de **tipo_usuario**. Si con 1 o 0, o si con texto.

Comment: Si ya probé eso. No se si el problema es con la variable registro que no logra acceder al campo tipo_cuenta de la tabla cuenta.